# Is it ok to access classes data members and perform operations on them in destructor?

Tags: c++, class, initialization, destructor, destroy

I have a big concert. We know that the initialization of (non static) data members of class is performed in constructors initialization list. So calling a function, even e virtual function (this does not act as polymorphic behavior) is ok and well defined by standard.

So I wander can we do same operations of destructor? At what point classes data members or vtable are invalid or corrupted? Are there any restrictions on operations in destructor (beside throwing an exception)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you test it?

Comment: Test what @ChristianSeverin?!!

Comment: @ChristianSeverin That would (might) merely show what one (possibly buggy) implementation does.  Much better to understand what guarantees the standard offers.

Comment: @MartinBonner: True.

Comment: @EduardRostomyan: Did you do any research at all? Google for, say, "c++ destructor"? Perform any basic tests?

Comment: @EduardRostomyan: (BTW, what is "a big concert" in your first sentence?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of your destructor's scope any remaining member variables are destroyed -- they are still alive in the destructor.